# How do I show Chinese (Non-ASCII) characters in URL

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS to develop an Chinese website. I used [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage the URL links, and the params for the URL is in Chinese.

Here is the code, `schoolName` is an variable in controller, and the value is Chinese characters:

`<a ui-sref="showSchools({name:schoolName})" > 查找</a>`

The problem is it will generate URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/showSchools?name=%E7%A6%8F%E5%BB%BA%E7%9C%81%E9%97%BD%E4%BE
```

But i want the link to be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/showSchools?name=第一中学
```

I tried encode param into utf8 with encodeUri filter: https://github.com/rubenv/angular-encode-uri, but it does not work.

Is there anybody know how to show Chinese characters in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but I thought it might help.

I too had this same issue while trying to display chinese characters in the url while testing a angular app (with ui-router) with localhost.

The urls used to appear as below:

```
http://localhost:56066/#/map/%E6%B1%9F%E8%8B%8F
```

But as soon as I added the below line to clean up the url:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
```

The urls now appear as below (which is what I hoped they would look like):

```
http://localhost:56066/map/黑龙江
```

I haven't yet figured out why cleaning up the url helped!